# HTML/CSS - Center nav bar of variable size

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I'm going to have a nav bar that lets a user sort through a gallery of pictures. The problem is the nav bar width is going to vary based on the size of the gallery, and when I don't set a width I can't use margin: 0 auto; to center the menu. (Instead, every shows up on the left side of the gallery container.)

Here's the html:

```
        <div id="nav_container">
            <div id="timeline_nav">
                <!--<a class="arrow left" />-->
                <a class="toggle"/>
                <a class="toggle"/>
                <a class="toggle"/>             
                <a class="toggle"/>
                <!--<a class="arrow right disabled" />-->
            </div>          
        </div>
```

And the css:

```
#nav_container { width:100%;height:20px; position:absolute; bottom:10px; background-color:#000;}
#timeline_nav { position:relative;margin:0 auto; }
#timeline_nav a { display:block; float:left; cursor:pointer; overflow:hidden; }
#timeline_nav a.toggle { width:4px; height:4px; padding:2px; margin:0 2px; background:url(http://images.apple.com/iphone/gallery/images/nav-ticks-20100607.png) 50% 0 no-repeat; }
```

**Any ideas how to fix this?**

Comment: you can apply display:inline-block, and that will give it a width (it doesnt work n ie6 thought).. also if you are using javascript for the gallery you can center it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is going to the left because you are using `float: left;`, which brings the achors outside of normal flow. What you probably meant to do was set the anchors to `display: inline-block;` and center the contents of the `DIV`. This should be supported in all browsers as IE6 supports `inline-block` on elements that are originally inline.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach in this case is to set the container element to `text-align: center;` and the element you want centered to `display: inline-block;`

You will have to set the centered element to display 'inline' in IE < 8;

```
#nav-container {
  text-align: center;
}

#timeline-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; /* IE6 and IE7 hack */
}
```

But i'm no Eric Meyer so...

Answer (score 0):

You could read the width by Javascript and add it dynamic to your #nav_container. 
Afterwards you can align the Container with margin: 0 auto;